# Русский язык в консоли Windows Mobile 5.0 (.net compact 3.5)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile

Нужно, чтобы в консоли выводились русские символы, но параметра `OutputEncoding` у класса `Console` нету. Как установить русский язык? Может нужно что-то отдельно подключить или настроить в самом устройстве?